# Bash folder lists with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code to find specific files that are over 10 MB:

```
[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: findlarge [PATHNAME]"; exit 0 ; }
FILES=`find $1 -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ";" }'`

echo -ne $FILES
```

It works quite well until it runs into a file path that has a space in it. So for example I have a folder that has a large file in it at `/var/www/html/Web Content/largefile.zip` but the script will only return `/var/www/html/Web`.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `$1` into quotes to handle the space, and use the `-printf` argument to output your file list:

```
[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: findlarge [PATHNAME]"; exit 0 ; }
find "$1" -type f -size +10000k -printf '%p;'
```

Using `;` to match your existing code, but you can substitute `\n` to output each file on its own line.

Comment: I still have the same result.

Comment: This still suffers from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: The awk is still using spaces to find $9. Really, you should just not try to parse `ls` output.  Use `find -printf` or `stat` or something.

Comment: Very true... I didn't catch that in my test output. Updated to correctly output on the filename using the `-printf` argument.

Comment: How do I get the file path as part of the output? I need `/var/www/html/Web Content/something with a space.zip` not just the file name... if possible.

Comment: Just updated... you need to include `%p` in the `-printf` argument.

Comment: If you remove %f that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: findlarge [PATHNAME]"; exit 0 ; }

FILES="$(find "$1" -type f -size +10000k -printf '%Ts %p\n' | cut -d ' ' -f2-)"

echo "$FILES"
```

Comment: Test OK with spaces in filenames.

Comment: Is there a way to also get the file path?

Comment: @sputnick Test this with filenames containing newlines (they're legal!) before you call it good.

Comment: Like whe said in another POST in the same situation, we keep the KISS principe. Who puts newlines in filenames ? Never seen that in =~ 10 years of *nix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @sputnick - just a VERY small improvement :) Add an EOL after printing the files. `echo -ne "$FILES\n"`

Comment: This is a non-modified line from original script from Peter. `echo` options removed.

Comment: @sputnick - :O I didn't know these `echo` options. Thanks!

Comment: @sputnick Attackers attempting to exploit bugs in your scripts do, for one. Lots of lulz to be had with files named `$'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be emitting the filenames with `-print0` (which is guaranteed to output them *exactly* as they exist on the filesystem), and storing them in an array (which is the only way to delimit between them which is guaranteed to work for all possible contents).

```
[[ -n "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: findlarge [PATHNAME]"; exit 0 ; }

files=()
while IFS='' read -d '' -r; do
  files+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(find "$1" -type f -size +10000k -print0)

printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Arrays in bash can contain any non-NUL characters, even newlines (which are valid in POSIX filenames). Other approaches are not guaranteed to preserve special characters which filenames may contain.

For more information on this general approach to processing output from find in bash, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: That throws: `./lftp.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./lftp.sh: line 12: `done < <(find "$1" -type f -size +10000k -print0)'`

Comment: @Peter Sounds like you're using `/bin/sh` rather than bash.